# How to inherit html tags or how remove component tags in DOM?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

a lot time wasted on this problem. I have the problem in two places. **I have 14.2.0 version of Angular.** The issue:

**I want to make a structure, at example:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">  //this first component
  <div class="row">            //this first component
    <div class="col-2"></div>  //this second component 
    <div class="col"></div>   //this third component
  </div>
</div>
```

**i made this:**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<app-sidenav>
  <sidenav-menu
    mdbCollapse
    #sidenav="mdbCollapse"
    id="sidenavId"
  >
<!--   <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>-->
  </sidenav-menu>


  <sidenav-content>
    <div class="bg-black text-white">hello </div>
  </sidenav-content>
</app-sidenav>
<div class="btn btn-primary"
      type="button"
     (click)="sidenav.toggle()"
     [attr.aria-expanded]="!sidenav.collapsed"
     aria-controls="sidenavId"
>show</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

But when I match all - all structure is showing incorrect. Because between my .row and .col-2 was created my component tag and all styles applied for my component, but not to my div with .col-2. I will show you below:

[between the divs was created my side-navmenu block and my div after him not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGPiN.jpg)

same situation was with map-frame. I wanted create component with map code(leaflet). Code worked good without refactor him in component. After refactor in component the code became work incorrect. What a magic happened with component? How correct inherit tags with angular cli?

I tried to find an info in Angular docs but found only about Encapsulated styles. It's not same. I think maybe tag of component miss in time server side rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In component decorator use:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[my-component]', //instead of 'my-component'
  ...
})
...
```

In parent component use:

```
<div my-component class="container-fluid">  
...
```

instead of `<my-component>`

Comment: No, i tried same. Yes, mycompanent tag dissapear, however between our styles still have mycompanent styles. Need to remove the layer

Comment: I wanted make all bootstrap classes inside component, but couldn't. Yes, decide only same. Thank you for help